# Pytorch ImageNet dataset

Tags: python, dataset, pytorch, imagenet

I am unable to download the original ImageNet dataset from their official website. However, I found out that pytorch has ImageNet as one of it’s torch vision datasets.

Q1. Is that the original ImageNet dataset?

Q2. How do I get the classes for the dataset like it’s being done in Cifar-10

```
classes = [‘airplane’, ‘automobile’, ‘bird’, ‘cat’, ‘deer’, ‘dog’, ‘frog’, ‘horse’, ‘ship’, ‘truck’]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `torchvision.datasets.ImageNet` is just a class which allows you to work with the ImageNet dataset. You have to download the dataset yourself (e.g. from http://image-net.org/download-images) and pass the path to it as the `root` argument to the ImageNet class object.

Note that the option to download it directly by passing the flag `download=True` is no longer possible:

```
if download is True:
    msg = ("The dataset is no longer publicly accessible. You need to "
           "download the archives externally and place them in the root "
           "directory.")
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
elif download is False:
    msg = ("The use of the download flag is deprecated, since the dataset "
           "is no longer publicly accessible.")
    warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
```

([source](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/imagenet.py))

If you just need to get the class names and the corresponding indices without downloading the whole dataset (e.g. if you are using a pretrained model and want to map the predictions to labels), then you can download them e.g. from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/deep-learning-models/image-models/imagenet_class_index.json) or from [this](https://gist.github.com/yrevar/942d3a0ac09ec9e5eb3a) github gist.

Comment: Thanks alot. Best regards!

Comment: It seems that the link http://image-net.org/download-images doesn't work: it offers to download the full dataset from http://www.image-net.org/archive/stanford/fall11_whole.tar, which yields a 404 error.

Comment: @GeoffreyNegiar did you find a solution?

Comment: The link http://image-net.org/download-images does work -- it has actually been recently updated with a version where all faces in the dataset are blurred.

Comment: A not-very-relevant question. Is there any version of Tiny ImageNet in original size of ImageNet? 256*256 instead of 64*64.

Comment: Data is available here https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/imagenet-object-localization-challenge/data now, but it is reorganized, see also https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/issues-with-dataloader-for-imagenet-should-i-use-datasets-imagefolder-or-datasets-imagenet/115742/6